# Primes and square offsets

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

For a prime $p$, define $\delta(p)$ to be the offset $d$, smallest
in absolute value, such that
$p \pm d = r^2$ for $d,r \in \mathbb{N}$. 
For example,
\begin{eqnarray}
\delta(11) & = & -2 \;:\; 11 -2 = 3^2 \\
\delta(29) & = & -4 \;:\; 29 - 4 = 5^2 \\
\delta(43) & = & 6 \;:\; 43 + 6 = 7^2 \\
\delta(191) & = & 5 \;:\; 191 + 5 = 14^2 
\end{eqnarray}
$\delta(p)$ is distributed as one might expect:

---

[image: delta vs p]

---

For a particular $\delta=d$ value, define $\Delta(n,d)$ to be the number
of primes $p$ at most $n$ with $\delta(p) = +d$, minus the number with $\delta(p) = -d$. In other words, $\Delta$ records the cumulative prevalence of $+d$ over $-d$. For example, $\Delta(59,5)=1$ because there is one more $+5$ than $-5$ up to
$n=59$:
$$
\delta(31)=5 \;,\; \delta(41)=-5 \;,\; \delta(59)=5
$$
If one tracks out this $\Delta(n,5)$ bias for larger values of $n$,
by $n=44939$, $+5$ has occured $28$ times more than $-5$,
with little sign of becoming more balanced:

---

[image: Bias]


<sup>Labels to the right are the $d$ values in $\Delta(n,d)$.</sup>

---

> ***Q***.
>   What explains these $\Delta(n,d)$ biases in favor of $+d$ over $-d$
>   or the reverse? Can the $\pm$ bias be predicted for a given $d$?
>   What is the growth rate of $\Delta(n,d)$?

Comment: Well, $\delta(p)=-4$ occurs more than $\delta(p)=4$ since $p+4=r^2$ implies $p=(r-2)(r+2)$ (so cannot happen at all for $p>5$). The same is true for all other squares (like $1$, $9$, etc.)

Comment: This might be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman%E2%80%93Horn_conjecture

Comment: I posted a version of this question on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/268372/6094).